# Adobe Coldfusion Railo OpenBD Apache Tomcat Multiple Sites

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, coldfusion, railo, openbd

Here's what I am trying to do, unless I am crazy:

I am trying to use Tomcat with the multiple workers, so far I got OpenBD working, but having trouble with Railo, and will be tackling Adobe after.

- each engine deployed as a war
- separated by different workers
- I wanted to keep both the sites and engines inside my sites directory
- I have to remap the symlink for the WEB-INF when I switch engines = have not found a way around this

my thought is to have everything separated into modules and I want to be able to execute both cfm and php code in a single site.  Ideally, it would be amazing if there would be a way to not have to remap the symlink as well.

thoughts? can this be done? I am trying to mimic how this would be setup on a live server, not using eclipse for example.  here is what I am working with so far:

**my apache workers.properties**

worker.list=openbd, openbdadmin, railo, railoadmin 

worker.openbd.type=ajp13 
worker.openbd.host=local.mydev.openbd
 
worker.openbd.port=8009

worker.openbdadmin.type=ajp13 
worker.openbdadmin.host=local.admin.openbd 
worker.openbdadmin.port=8009  

worker.railo.type=ajp13
 
worker.railo.host=local.mydev.railo
 
worker.railo.port=8009

worker.railoadmin.type=ajp13 
worker.railoadmin.host=local.admin.railo 
worker.railoadmin.port=8009

**my tomcat servers.xml**


< Host name="local.admin.openbd" 
appBase="/Users/[myusername]/Websites/coldfusion.engines" 
unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="true"
xmlNamespaceAware="false">
        
< Context path="" docBase="openbd/"
reloadable="true" privileged="true" 
antiResourceLocking="false" anitJARLocking="false" allowLinking="true">

< /Host>

< Host name="local.admin.railo"  
appBase="/Users/[my username]/Websites/coldfusion.engines"
unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
        
< Context path="" docBase="railo/" 
reloadable="true" privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" 
anitJARLocking="false" allowLinking="true">

< /Host>

< Host name="local.mydev.openbd"  
appBase="/Users/[my username]/Websites/coldfusion.engines"
unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

< Context path="" docBase="/Users/[my username]/Websites/example.mydev/wwwroot/" 
reloadable="true" privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" 
anitJARLocking="false" allowLinking="true">< /Context>

< /Host>

< Host name="local.mydev.railo"  
appBase="/Users/[my username]/Websites/coldfusion.engines" 
unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

< Context path="" docBase="/Users/[my username]/Websites/example.mydev/wwwroot/" 
reloadable="true" privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" 
anitJARLocking="false" allowLinking="true">

< /Host>

**my apache vhosts**

ServerName local.admin.openbd
    DocumentRoot /Users/[my username]/Websites/coldfusion.engines/openBD/
    #Mount OpenBD and tell it to only server cfml files
    JkMount /*.cfm openbdadmin

    ErrorLog "/Users/[my username]/Websites/apache.logs/local_openbdadmin_error.log"





    ServerName local.admin.railo

    DocumentRoot /Users/[my username]/Websites/coldfusion.engines/railo/

    #Mount Railo and tell it to only server cfml files

    JkMount /*.cfm railoadmin
    ErrorLog "/Users/[my username]/Websites/apache.logs/local_railoadmin_error.log"


    ServerName local.mydev
    DocumentRoot /Users/[my username]/Websites/example.mydev/wwwroot
    ErrorLog "/Users/[my username]/Websites/apache.logs/local_example_mydev_error.log"

ServerName local.mydev.openbd
    DocumentRoot /Users/[my username]/Websites/example.mydev/wwwroot
    #Mount OpenBD and tell it to only server cfml files
    JkMount /*.cfm openbd

    ErrorLog "/Users/[my username]/Websites/apache.logs/local_example_mydev_openbd_error.log"





    ServerName local.mydev.railo

    DocumentRoot /Users/[my username]/Websites/example.mydev/wwwroot

    JkMount /*.cfm railo
    ErrorLog "/Users/[my username]/Websites/apache.logs/local_example_mydev_railo_error.log"

**my folder structure I am using**

websites/apache.logs/
websites/coldfusion.engines/
websites/coldfusion.engines/cfusion/
websites/coldfusion.engines/openBD/
websites/coldfusion.engines/railo/
websites/example.mydev/
websites/example.mydev/wwwroot/
websites/example.mydev/wwwroot/index.cfm  
websites/example.mydev/wwwroot/index.htm  
websites/example.mydev/wwwroot/index.php

**error log output**
[Thu Aug 27 00:54:50.443 2009] [11279:2686719776] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3183): mod_jk/1.2.28 initialized

[Thu Aug 27 00:54:51.346 2009] [11280:2686719776] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3183): mod_jk/1.2.28 initialized

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:18.963 2009] [11284:2686719776] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (594): connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 failed (errno=61)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:18.963 2009] [11284:2686719776] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (922): Failed opening socket to (127.0.0.1:8009) (errno=61)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:18.963 2009] [11284:2686719776] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1507): (openbdadmin) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=61)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:18.963 2009] [11284:2686719776] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2447): (openbdadmin) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:19.063 2009] [11284:2686719776] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (594): connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 failed (errno=61)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:19.063 2009] [11284:2686719776] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (922): Failed opening socket to (127.0.0.1:8009) (errno=61)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:19.063 2009] [11284:2686719776] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1507): (openbdadmin) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=61)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:19.063 2009] [11284:2686719776] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2447): (openbdadmin) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:19.063 2009] [11284:2686719776] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2466): (openbdadmin) connecting to tomcat failed.

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:19.063 2009] [11284:2686719776] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2615): Service error=-3 for worker=openbdadmin

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:20.377 2009] [11283:2686719776] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (594): connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 failed (errno=61)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:20.377 2009] [11283:2686719776] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (922): Failed opening socket to (127.0.0.1:8009) (errno=61)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:20.377 2009] [11283:2686719776] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1507): (railoadmin) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=61)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:20.377 2009] [11283:2686719776] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2447): (railoadmin) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:20.477 2009] [11283:2686719776] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (594): connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 failed (errno=61)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:20.477 2009] [11283:2686719776] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (922): Failed opening socket to (127.0.0.1:8009) (errno=61)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:20.477 2009] [11283:2686719776] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1507): (railoadmin) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=61)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:20.477 2009] [11283:2686719776] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2447): (railoadmin) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:20.477 2009] [11283:2686719776] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2466): (railoadmin) connecting to tomcat failed.

[Thu Aug 27 00:55:20.477 2009] [11283:2686719776] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2615): Service error=-3 for worker=railoadmin

Comment: ok, this appears to happen when I attempt to have 2 wars configured at the same time, if I setup one or the other I can get openbd or railo to work........hmmmm..............

Comment: I was able to so far get railo and openbd setup using multiple instances of tomcat, not sure if this is the best approach since it appears to suck a ton of memory, however, using the correct applescript commands to start only the instance i want to work in this approach may work, not sure yet, more to come

Answer (score 1):

You generally want your Tomcat Host's appbase="webapps" (default) and have the Context's docBase point to your Web root (docBase="/Users/[my username]/Websites/example.mydev/wwwroot/"). Your Web root will contain a WEB-INF for whichever WAR you're using (ColdFusion/OpenBD/Railo). It sounds like you're using a symlink or something for the WEB-INF dir?

In any case, you can't run requests against 3 different WARs in the same Web root (at least not without some fancy connector stuff--you could let a JRun instance/connector run while having WEB-INF of Railo *or* OpenBD in the Web root to then use 2 different Apache vhosts to handle... but this all sounds messy:). So, since you can't run them at the same time with this setup, I'm not sure why you're using separate host names?

It's also worth noting that you'll likely need to restart the Tomcat service each time you replace (re-map symlink) the WEB-INF folder.

Finally, if you do have the same Web root (docBase) for all three Tomcat Host entries, I'd imagine this will most certainly cause problems -- this could be the root of your errors, but not sure. Since you want the same Web root for each host, you might as well use an Alias (or just one host), something like this:

```
<Host name="local.mydev" appBase="webapps">
<Alias>local.mydev.railo</Alias>
<Alias>local.mydev.openbd</Alias>
<Context path="" docBase="/Users/[my username]/Websites/example.mydev/wwwroot" />
</Host>
```

Comment: after having, to say the least, tons of fun with it, I ended up rolling back to a jrun installation and I will be installing CF9 into it this weekend.